# Socket.io two clients communicating only in one direction

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm building a simple socket.io app using React and Express and have encountered a problem where two clients are having issues with sending data to each other.
For example: Player 1 connects to the server and then does Player 2.
Player 1 can receive an invitation from Player 2, but in a opposite situation not. The one that connects second to the server seems not to receive invitations.

Console log from Player 1:

```
Sending an invitation to player:  029bdef2-7f1b-43a0-9d3e-02ff79728a6e
Invitation from 029bdef2-7f1b-43a0-9d3e-02ff79728a6e
```

Console log from Player 2:

```
Sending an invitation to player:  83a594c4-4dae-47a2-90c4-339e1d55d287
```

Logs from the server console:

```
from: 2ad4f74f-ca78-4e96-80c6-9d3ff810681c
to:
beccb53f-3b8a-4ea6-994e-93eae19df715
from:
beccb53f-3b8a-4ea6-994e-93eae19df715
to:
2ad4f74f-ca78-4e96-80c6-9d3ff810681c
```

My client code:

```
invitationHandler = ({ id = null, socketId = null }) => {
    console.log('Sending an invitation to player: ', id)
    const { socket } = this.props
    socket.emit(INVITATION, { id, socketId })
    socket.on(INVITATION, ({ id }) => {
      console.log('Invitation from ' + id)
    })
  }
```

Server code:

```
socket.on(INVITATION, ({ id = null, socketId = null }) => {
    console.log('from: ')
    console.log(socket.user.id)
    console.log('to: ')
    console.log(id)
    socket.to(socketId).emit(INVITATION, { id: socket.user.id })
  })
```

Comment: It seems you're client only sets up their invitation handler after they emit an invitation. The second player not receiving invitations is probably due to the fact that they haven't yet emitted an invite, and therefore don't have a way to handle invites yet.

Comment: @daviscodesbugs It works, thank you! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply moving

```
socket.on(INVITATION, ({ id }) => {
      console.log('Invitation from ' + id)
    })
```

to another function that gets executed earlier than the one containing *socket.emit*.
The handler needs to be set up before any data arrives.